# where in condition codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter active record query for where in condition.

```
<?php
    foreach($std->result() as $stds_id) {
        $stid[] = $stds_id->std_id; 
        print_r($stid);
    }
```

what actually i want to pass is where_in is `Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 4 )`

but it prints like

```
Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 4 )
```

I don't know how to pass it.

my model:

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where_in($field,$id);
    $getdata=$this->db->get($table);
    return $getdata;
```

Comment: your query is ok and `$stid` is ok too. Just print it outside the `foreach` loop.Just call the model function after foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite fine, just you need to take out the array you're making inside foreach.

```
$stid = array();
foreach($std->result() as $stds_id) {
        $stid[] = $stds_id->std_id;
}

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where_in('stid', $stid);
$this->db->get();
return $this->db->result();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `foreach` loop with following

```
foreach ($std->result() as $stds_id) {
    $stid[] = $stds_id->std_id; 
}
 print_r($stid);
```

And use this query for where in condition

```
$this->db->where_in('stid', $stid);
```